# Need to Search an csv file and run an if/Where statement on the value to initialize a bat file

Tags: powershell, cmd, path, import-csv, start-process

Want to clear my cache once the system memory usage exceeds `70%`
I have a task scheduler to start monitoring, a data collection for the performance log with report exported to csv, a custom event view to trigger the clearing, and a bat file to clear the cache.

This is the last piece to my puzzle.

Everything in cmd and powershell to my knowledge has been used

It has a header with three fields, and then 4 cells on information. (`A2`, `B2`, `A3`, `B3`)

```
powershell -command {Import-Csv -Path 'C:\PerfLogs\Admin\New Data Collector Set\Memory DataCollector01.csv' | Where{ $_.B3 -gt  "70.000000000000000"} | start-process $env:userprofile\Desktop\creatvent.bat}\
```

This is the performance report output in power shell and on notepad:

```
(PDH-CSV 4.0) (Eastern Daylight Time)(240) \\LT305-MIA\Memory\% Committed Bytes In Use Collect memory data usage percentage
------------------------------------------ ------------------------------------------- ------------------------------------  
08/19/2019 12:18:32.480                   41.363952528071579  
08/19/2019 12:19:32.467                   41.291049993897566


"(PDH-CSV 4.0) (Eastern Daylight Time)(240)","\\LT305-MIA\Memory\% Committed Bytes In Use","Collect memory data usage percentage"
"08/19/2019 15:38:37.582","47.54470529676059"," "
"08/19/2019 15:39:37.569","47.43784841788883"," "
```

I'd like to have this code work properly. Right know it runs everytime (no matter the value) i need it to run properly.

Comment: From where did these names (A2, B2, A3, and B3) originate? The third column appears to be memory utilization. Is that correct?

Comment: Could you please add the output as formatted text in the question itself? In a comment it is hard to read and it looks like there are lines at the beginning that make the content not a valid csv..

Comment: @lit the names I added for reference and yes the data are memory usages. -Theo will try and edit more clearly.

Comment: @Theo the .csv is valid and the code triggers the event. Just not properly.

Comment: Try removing the QUOTATION MARKs from `70`. `{ $_.B3 -gt  70 }`

Comment: Did try it. It runs at    30 and    99

Comment: The file you are showing has 1) terrible column headers and 2) just three fields, not four as you state in the question. The third field being just a space character, meaning the _Collect memory data usage percentage_ seems to fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your file (as you show it) only has three columns with actual data and uses not really friendly headers, I suggest you do it like this:

- Read the file as string array with `Get-Content`.
- Skip the ugly header line
- Convert the rest of the lines to CSV using custom headers
- use a `Where-Object` clause to search for a value in the 2nd column that has a numeric greater than 70

```
if (Get-Content -Path 'C:\PerfLogs\Admin\New Data Collector Set\Memory DataCollector01.csv' | 
    Select-Object -Skip 1 | 
    ConvertFrom-Csv -Header 'Date','MemoryUsage','DataUsage' | 
    Where-Object { [int]$_.MemoryUsage -gt 70 }) {
        # in here, run your .bat file to clear the cache
        Start-Process "$env:userprofile\Desktop\creatvent.bat"
}
```

Comment: Windows blg files, huh?  Super big help...this would have broken my head for days. +1 rep

Comment: `Where-Object { [int]$_.MemoryUsage -gt 70 }`  [int] here is [0] for the first line and [1] for the second?  The rest makes sense

Comment: @Andrew I was using the (what I thought was the notepad view) of the output you showed. That is the last three lines where the data is quoted and comma delimited. If what you show is all in one file, then skip all the lines including the not-so-friendly headers. In your example `Select-Object -Skip 7`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I didn't understand it correctly, this is my sample .csv:

```
h1;h2;h3;
08/19/2019;12:18:32.460;41.363952528071579
08/19/2019;12:19:32.467;41.291049993897566
08/19/2019;12:18:31.480;78.363952528073254
```

And executing this code:

```
Import-Csv .\file.csv -Delimiter ";" | Where-Object -Property h3 -gt 77
```

Results in console showing:

```
h1         h2           h3
--         --           --
08/19/2019 12:18:31.480 78.363952528073254
```

Can you try it and let know of the outcome?

Comment: My output is as shows above. Using the Delimiter, a parameter type 'System.Char' is required. Using only 'Where-Object -Property _headerinfo_ -gt 77, it states cannot bind 'Delimiter' and cannot convert Data to type System.Char